# Taking a picture in Background Service

Tags: android, root

I am searching for a method to take a picture with the Camera of my phone without showing the User a Preview.

I know, that this is designed not to work, because its a security issue, but I am developing a "Get My Phone Back" app, that should be able to identify the thief, that has stolen my phone (in future^^).
So it has to be stealth.

My phone is rooted, so I think there should be a way to do this.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:
You could start the camera just as described inside the docs, but set the underlying SurfaceView visibility to (View.GONE or View.INVISIBLE). After that, you can try to take pictures...

Not really shure, if this will work, but I think its worth a try

Comment: but for that an activity has to be launched, isn't it? The user would recognize this behaviour.